# Associate task with row

Tags: vba, ms-project

I built a form that has a "Done" button that changes the font of the selected cells to Grey and Strikethrough.

```vb
Sub SetTaskNameFontDone()

    Dim T As Task
    
    If Not (ActiveSelection.Tasks Is Nothing) Then
        For Each T In ActiveSelection.Tasks
            ' Test for blank task row
            If Not (T Is Nothing) Then
                SelectTaskField Row:=T.ID, Column:="Name", RowRelative:=False
                Font32Ex Color:=8355711
                Font32Ex Strikethrough:=True
            End If
        Next T
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that the Row number seems to be a physical location number, i.e. position from the top of the sheet. So if you "close" a task that has subtasks, then the Row number is no longer the same as the Task ID, and the formatting is applied to the wrong row.

```
Case 1: Sheet when task is open:
VBA Row #     TaskID     Task
1               1        ParentTask1  (open)
2               2            SubTask1-1
3               3        ParentTask2

Case 2:  Sheet when task is closed (note change in row number)
VBA Row #     TaskID     Task
1               1        ParentTask1  (closed)
2               3        ParentTask2
```

Two possible approaches:

1. I could do OutlineShowAllTasks at the start of the routine, but that changes the way the outline appears. I haven't found an indicator for which tasks are open, so I can't memorize and restore that, as a compensation for OutlineShowAllTasks.
2. Save the target Task IDs, and then loop through all the rows, and compare the Task ID for each row. However, I haven't found a way to loop through all the rows and get the Task ID from the row.

How do I associate the selected task with the proper row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c99cbac1-b886-48a5-8d1b-37df2c5caaec/ms-project-vba-associate-task-with-row?forum=project2010custprog

```
Sub SetTaskNameFontDone()
Dim T As Task
For Each T In ActiveSelection.Tasks
    Font32Ex Color:=8355711
    Font32Ex Strikethrough:=True
Next T
End Sub
```