# MS Project VBA - Iterate by display row number

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a problem using `for` loop in this MS Project VBA Macro:

```
Sub Check_Change_Article()
    Dim ProjTasks As Tasks
    Dim ProjTask As Task
    Dim Art As String
    Dim ArtOld As String
    Set ProjTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks
    ArtOld = " "
    For Each ProjTask In ProjTasks             
    If Not (ProjTask Is Nothing) Then        
        Art =ProjTask.Text22
        If (Art != ArtOld) Then
            ProjTask.Text4 = "CHANGE"
        End If
        ArtOld = Art
    End If
    Next ProjTask
End Sub
```

Project Example

```
Case 1: Sheet when task is open:         
VBA Row #     TaskID     Text22    Text4 
1               1        PNL50R    CHANGE
2               2        PNL50R          
3               3        JPL50Y    CHANGE
```

```
Case 2:  User can filter, group or order tasks (note change in row number)
VBA Row #     TaskID     Text22    Text4
1               3        PNL50R    CHANGE
2               1        PNL50R    CHANGE
3               2        JPL50Y
```

I read this discussion:
[ms project VBA associate task with row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190730/ms-project-vba-associate-task-with-row)

Using `ActiveSelection.Tasks` instead of `ActiveProject.Tasks` I see that `for` loop iterates follow VBA Rows.

Is it possible to set for a loop to iterate by VBA Row Number, without using `ActiveSelection` (if it's possible, I wouldn't force the user to select rows)?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe

Answer (score 2):

You can use Application.SelectSheet (so that the user does not have to manually select the tasks). Then you can loop through the ActiveSelection.Tasks collection. When done you can use Application.SelectBeginning to select only the first task.